# Can't boot windows partition

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning, mount, hard-drive

**What I have?**
500gb harddrive 
- 500gb for Windows

1000gb harddrive
 
- 500gb for Ubuntu
- 500gb for Extra Storage

**Problem Description**
I am unable to boot my computer except by USB at the moment. So I booted into Ubuntu via USB, and tried to see if I could mount my Ubuntu Partition. However, everytime I tried, it would say unrecognized file system.

I've been searching all over online trying to figure out how to get my computer working but made no progress so if you could help, I would greatly appreciate that. Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at [EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/)

Answer (score 0):

check whether grub2 is installed on the master hard disk. Does window load properly? if yes, then install grub2 on the 500gb hard disk else install it on 1000gb hard disk.